# script stays in Oracle db

Tags: linux, oracle

When I use this script :

```
sqlplus -s "/ as sysdba" << EOF
startup;
EOF
```

It starts db and returns to host.  I want my script doesn't return to host.  Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it help if you add `exit` to your script? In other words, if you try something like:

```
sqlplus -s "/ as sysdba" << EOF
startup;
exit
EOF
```

**EDIT**: if you don't want SQL*Plus to exit after running `startup`, put the line

```
startup;
```

in a file named `startup.sql`, say. You can then run

```
sqlplus -s "/ as sysdba" @startup.sql
```

That should then start the database and leave you in SQL*Plus.

Comment: No it doesn't help I wannt something like that
lsnrctl start
sqlplus -s "/ as sysdba" << EOF
startup;
exit
EOF
After execution this script returns to host

Comment: I don't understand.  What do you mean by 'this script returns to host'?

Comment: when i use this script it connects to database as sysdba, starts the database and then disconnects from the database returns to host(to linux environment)